# Method getPath called in onBeforeRendering returns undefined

Tags: sapui5

I have a List Report which, once selected an item, prompts to an Object Page.  I am using no FIORI Elements, everything was created from scratch.
The object page has a static header, but its body changes from item to item.  In essence, the body uses different fragments that depends on a field (Position Type) of the selected item.  In other words:

- Pos Type 1 ---> fragment A
- Pos Type 2 ---> fragment B

To do all this, on the controller of the object page, I have implemented the following withing the onBeforeRendering lifecycle method:

```
    onBeforeRendering: function() {
        // // Set Fragment to be used
        var oLayout = this.getView().byId("ObjectPageLayout"), 
            oFragment = sap.ui.xmlfragment(this._fragmentName());
        oLayout.addSection(oFragment);  
    },
    _fragmentName: function() {
        var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
        var sPosType = oModel.getProperty(this.getView().getObjectBinding().getPath() + "/PositionType");
        var sFragment;

        if (sPosType === "1") {
            sFragment = "A";
        } else if (sPosType === "2") {
             sFragment = "B";
        }
        return sFragment;
    },
```

The problem I am facing is that this code is throwing the following error message: "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPath' of undefined"

The only way I found to make this to work is by, instead of using method onBeforeRendering, I used onInit.  This way, getPath() works fine.  But if the user goes back to the List Report, and then selects an item of a different Position Type, then the Object Page displays the same fragment used in the previous item selected.

In case you wonder, bellow you will find the object view:

```
<mvc:View height="100%" xmlns="sap.uxap" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:m="sap.m" xmlns:semantic="sap.m.semantic"
xmlns:forms="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout" controllerName="objectview.controller"
xmlns:aud="sap.uxap.sample.SharedBlocks.fragmentblocks">
<semantic:FullscreenPage id="page" navButtonPress="onNavBack" showNavButton="true" title="{i18n>ObjectPageTitle}">
<m:Page title="Object Page Title">
    <m:content>
        <ObjectPageLayout id="ObjectPageLayout">
            <headerTitle>
                <ObjectPageHeader id="ItemTitle" objectTitle="Item Title">
                    <actions>
                        Some actions defined

                    </actions>
                </ObjectPageHeader>
            </headerTitle>
            <headerContent>
                Some Header Content
            </headerContent>
            <sections>

            </sections>
        </ObjectPageLayout>
    </m:content>
    <m:footer>
        <m:Bar>
            <m:contentRight>
                Buttons added to the Footer
            </m:contentRight>
        </m:Bar>
    </m:footer>     
</m:Page>
</semantic:FullscreenPage>
```

Comment: Finnally I was able to solve this (partially as of now).  Problem was that in all lifecycle methods, getpath won't return anything.  By using onObjectMatched (set on onInit), I can get the arguments and from there decide which fragment should be called next.

The problem I have now is that this solution keeps adding content to the section control every time an item is selected.  So i need to know how to destroy/remove/delete content from only the Section control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that each time you go to the page you add a new section on the container of sections.

You can remove all the existent sections before adding the new one.

```
oLayout.removeAllSections();
oLayout.addSection(oFragment);
```